# Python 3.x tkinter importing error

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, importerror

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. When importing tkinter I get these following error, though it seems I've installed python-tk somehow. Please help.

```
shishir@dewsworld:~$ python3.2
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  5 2011, 22:09:30) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from tkinter import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named _tkinter

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package')
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
>>> 
[2]+  Stopped                 python3.2
shishir@dewsworld:~$ sudo apt-get install python-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-tk is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 mutter-common libcaribou0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0
  caribou libmutter0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gjs gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 cups-pk-helper gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0
  gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-gee-1.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is wrong. Install `python3-tk` instead.