# Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, modulenotfounderror

I have seen many different things go wrong when trying to use the Tkinter standard library package, or its related functionality (turtle graphics using `turtle` and the built-in IDLE IDE), or with third-party libraries that have this as a dependency (e.g. displaying graphical windows with Matplotlib).

It seems that even when there isn't a [problem caused by shadowing the name of the standard library modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353) (this is a common problem for beginners trying to follow a tutorial and use turtle graphics - [example 1](/q/60480328); [example 2](/q/17530140); [example 3](/q/53692691); [example 4](/q/32180949)), **it commonly happens that the standard library Tkinter just doesn't work**. This is a big problem because, again, a lot of beginners try to follow tutorials that use turtle graphics and blindly assume that the `turtle` standard library will be present.

The error might be reported:

- As [`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540); or an `ImportError` with the same message; or with different casing (I am aware that [the name changed from `Tkinter` in 2.x to `tkinter` in 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843596); that is a different problem).
- Similarly, but [referring to an internal `_tkinter` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444), and displaying code with a comment that says "If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk"; or [with a custom error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884075) that says "please install the python-tk package" or similar.
- As "No module named turtle" [when trying to use `turtle` specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318093), or one of the above errors.
- [When trying to display a plot using Matplotlib](/q/56656777); commonly, this will happen after trying to change the backend, which was set by default to avoid trying to use Tkinter.

**Why do problems like this occur**, when Tkinter is [documented as being part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)? How can I **add or repair the missing standard library functionality**? Are there any special concerns for specific Python environments?

---

<sub>See also: ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777) . It is possible to use other GUI backends with Matplotlib to display graphs; but if the `TkAgg` backend does not work, that is because of a missing or faulty Tkinter install.</sub>

<sub>In Python 3.x, the name of the Tkinter standard library module was corrected from `Tkinter` to `tkinter` (i.e., all lowercase) in order to maintain consistent naming conventions. Please use [Difference between tkinter and Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843596) to close duplicate questions caused by trying to use the old name in 3.x (or the new name in 2.x). This question is about cases where Tkinter is not actually available. If it isn't clear which case applies, please either offer both duplicate links, or close the question as "needs debugging details".</sub>

Comment: This is an attempt at an artificial canonical duplicate. I already have several questions earmarked to dupe-hammer to here; a few of the popular questions I linked here should remain open, but I'm hoping this question will be a better dupe target for most new questions.

Comment: Help wanted: looking for information about various "special" environments like QGIS, debug builds (as described in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743762) etc.

Comment: One very specific hiccup with PyPy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764766 And with PyInstaller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135408/

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613117

Comment: Why are you closing older questions as duplicates of this newer question? If this question is newer, isn't it by definition a duplicate of the older questions?

Comment: Closing a question that is over 8 years old, has a score of nearly 400 and has been viewed 900,000 times as a duplicate of an "artificial canonical" seems a bit excessive.

Comment: @CarlG, age is not a factor when considering which question is the duplicate. The quality of each question, and their answers, should be used to determine which is the "dupe" and which is canonical. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/354577

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I would say this case from that meta answer applies: "If they differ based on the versions of the relevant systems, then they're not really exact duplicates." My question is specific to pyenv (which makes it easier for pyenv users to find and faster to fix their issue) while this artificial canonical tries to address the problem theoretically, and links back to mine for pyenv specifically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760839 was marked as a duplicate when it's really targeting OSX users, this question and it's answers don't address what people searching for that problem. That said, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76105219/7839535 provides a solution but not as targeted as the question's answers I referenced.

Comment: @IuriGuilherme In the main answer, I back-link that Q&A while giving what I believe to be a fair summary of the Mac-specific aspects of the issue. I wrote this one because a general understanding is necessary for the issue (in particular, the advice to avoid Pip applies regardless of platform) and because platform-specific aspects are really just finer detail. The common threads here are that there are platform-agnostic reasons Tkinter might be missing; you need to do system package-management or build-from-source type things to get it; and there are dependencies external to Python itself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree and disagree with you at the same time. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74661242/7839535) on the referenced question gives enough depth without addressing every aspect of the problem, which may be of no interest to people who just want to make it work on a Macbook for example. And even with all your research, the subject can be further explained, so where to draw the line remains to the scope of the question. This is not wikipedia IMO

Comment: Sorry, but this reads like a blog-post or a tutorial, and not a question/answer (which is the focus of Stack Overflow)...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### WARNING: Do not use `pip` to try to solve the problem

**The Pip package manager cannot help to solve the problem. No part of the Python standard library - including `tkinter`, `turtle` etc. - can be installed from PyPI. For security reasons, PyPI now blocks packages using names that match the standard library.**

There are many packages on PyPI that may look suitable, but are not. Most are simply wrappers that try to add a little functionality to the standard library Tkinter. However, one especially problematic package is `turtle`. It should not be there, because [current policy (since 2017) is to block packages with names that match the standard library](https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/issues/2151); but it was uploaded long before that, and has not been maintained since. It is **Python 2.x specific code that [will break during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318093)** on Python 3, is **extremely out of date** (published in 2009) and - most importantly - **has nothing whatsoever to do with turtle graphics**. I am [currently attempting](https://github.com/pypi/support/issues/2771) to get it delisted from PyPI.

### Why some Python installations don't include Tkinter components

There are several reasons why Tkinter might be missing, depending on the platform (although generally, the *motivation* is probably just to save space).

- When Python is installed on Windows using the official installer, there is an option to include or exclude Tcl/Tk support.
- Python installations that come pre-installed with Linux may exclude Tkinter, or various components, according to the distro maintainer's policy. For example, the Python that came with my copy of Linux included the `turtle` standard library, but not the underlying Tkinter package:

  ```
  >>> import turtle
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
      import tkinter as TK
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
  ```

  Other builds might not include the `turtle` module either.
- Python built from source might be missing Tkinter support because of deliberately chosen configuration options, or because dependencies were missing before starting compilation.

Note that **virtual environments will generally have the same Tkinter support as the Python installation they're based upon**. However, adding Tkinter support to the base **might not update the virtual environment**. In this case, it will be necessary to re-create the virtual environment from scratch. **It is [not possible to add or remove Tkinter support for an individual virtual environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738583).** This is because a virtual environment only differs from its base in terms of the site packages, and there is no site package for Tkinter (since, again, it is a standard library component that **cannot be obtained using Pip**).

### How to add Tkinter support, depending on the environment

**See also**:

- Guide in the official Tk documentation: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html
- Some previous (now duplicate) versions of the question with some useful answers:

  - [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810)
  - [Tkinter: "Python may not be configured for Tk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459444)
  - [ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540)

#### Windows

For Python installed using the official installer from python.org, use the operating system features to choose to **"repair" the installation** (or, if acceptable, uninstall and reinstall Python). This time, make sure to **check the option to install the "tcl/tk and IDLE"** optional feature.

Some legacy setups [may have had issues with conflicts between 32- and 64-bit versions of Python and Tcl/Tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724729). This should not cause problems on new setups.

For the embeddable zip package, see [Python embeddable zip: install Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710205) .

#### Linux: Python that came with the Linux distribution

If the Python that came with your Linux distribution doesn't include Tkinter, consider leaving that alone and installing a separate version of Python - just on general principle. However, in general, Tkinter support can be added to the *system* Python using the **system package manager (not Pip)**.

It will **typically be necessary to use `sudo` (not included in examples here)** to make such changes to the system Python.

- On **Ubuntu and Debian** based systems (including Pop!_OS, Ubuntu-based Mint): use `apt-get install python3-tk`, assuming the system Python is a 3.x version. For 2.x legacy systems, use `apt-get install python-tk` instead. In some cases it may be necessary to specify a minor version, like `apt-get install python3.11-tk`. [In some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532547), a custom exception message may say to install `python-tk` even though `python3-tk` should actually be installed instead.
- For **Fedora**, use `dnf install python3-tkinter`, as described by d-coder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25905642).
- For **Arch**, use `pacman -S tk`, as described by Jabba [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901234).
- For **RHEL**, use `yum install python3-tkinter`, as described by amzy-0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66292120).

#### Linux: Python built from source

The above packages can *only* add Tkinter support to the *system* python (the one installed in `/usr/bin`, which is used by the operating system to run essential scripts). They *cannot* add Tkinter support to a separate Python built from source. This is because, *in addition to* the actual Tcl/Tk library, using Tkinter in Python requires a per-installation "binding" library (referred to as `_tkinter` in the Python source code). **System packages will not add this library to other Python installations**.

Therefore, **install a *development* Tk package first** (e.g. `apt-get install tk-dev`) and try rebuilding.

See also:

- [Unable to install tkinter with pyenv Pythons on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469202) (using `pyenv`)
- [Install tkinter and python locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948295) (in case `sudo` privileges are not available)
- [Building Python and more on missing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171210) (more generally about rebuilding Python from source and filling in development dependencies)

#### Brew (typically MacOS)

Use `brew install python-tk`; if necessary, specify a Python version like `brew install python-tk@3.11`.

For non-system installations, it may be necessary to re-install and specify that Tkinter support should be included, like `brew install python --with-tcl-tk`. See also: [Why does Python installed via Homebrew not include Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760839)

#### Headless environments

It's **generally not possible to install Tkinter - or any other GUI toolkit** - for [headless server environments like PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/TkinterPygameEtc) or [Amazon Linux EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675417). The code will run on a remote server, so there is no monitor to display the GUI; while it would be possible in principle for the code to send commands back to the client that the client could then use to create a GUI, in general the server will have no knowledge of the client's environment. Making this work would require setting up some communication protocol ahead of time ([such as X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276168/what-is-x11-exactly)).

#### Virtual environments

First, **fix the installation that the virtual environment is based upon**. If this doesn't resolve the problem, **re-create the virtual environment** (and reinstall everything that was installed in the old virtual environment). Unfortunately, there is not a clean way around this. It might be possible to patch around the problem by changing a bunch of symlinks, but this is not supported.

If it is not possible to fix the base installation (for example, due to not having `sudo` rights on the system), **consider installing a separate Python** (for example, by compiling from source), ensuring that it is installed with Tkinter support, and creating virtual environments from *that* Python.

### Tkinter components

Some users will find it useful to understand exactly what the Tkinter system contains. There are several components:

- The underlying Tcl/Tk library, written in C. Some systems may independently have a Tcl/Tk installation that is unusable from Python by default.
- The `_tkinter` implementation module, which is also written in C and which interfaces between Python and Tcl/Tk ("tkinter" means "Tk interface"). This is an implementation detail, and should not be imported directly in Python user code. (the [C code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c) for this dates all the way back to 1994!)
- The `tkinter` package itself, which provides wrappers for the lower-level `_tkinter` interface, as well as `ttk` (a separate interface for newer "themed" widgets).
- Higher-level components, such as IDLE and `turtle`.

**Any given installation could theoretically be missing any or all of these components.** For system installations of Python on Linux and MacOS, the distro maintainer is responsible for making sure that the appropriate package (`python3-tk` or similar) installs whichever parts are missing by default, to the appropriate places.

As [explained to me on GitHub by Terry Jan Reedy](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/102501): when the **Windows** installer is told to install Tcl/Tk, it **will install a separate copy** of that library (and the corresponding `_tkinter` and `tkinter` etc.) for that Python installation. **On Linux, Tcl/Tk will normally come with Linux**; packages like `python3-tk` will add a `_tkinter` that uses the system Tcl/Tk, and a `tkinter` package (which will naturally find and use the `_tkinter` implementation, using the normal import mechanism).

**Since the Tcl/Tk installation is thus "vendored" for Windows, the Tcl/Tk version will depend on the Python version. On Linux it will depend on the system**, and it should be possible to use the system package manager to upgrade Tcl/Tk independently of Python. Note in particular that newer versions of Python might not be able to work with an outdated system Tcl/Tk. (To check the Tcl/Tk version *for a working installation*, see [How to determine what version of python3 tkinter is installed on my linux machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999344) .)

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps others like me who use `venv` and have multiple python versions (e.g. 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10) side by side on the same system.
Suppose you created your `venv` with a specific python version, and can't import `tkinter`:

```
$ python3.10 -m venv my_venv_1 #create a venv with python 3.10
$ source my_venv_1/bin/activate
$ python
Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:10) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
>>> quit()
$ deactivate
```

You can specifically install `tkinter` for the python version that matches the python version of the `venv` you created before. For example on ubuntu, you then need to install `tkinter` for your existing system wide python 3.10 specifically with this command:

`sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk`

Now if you activate the `venv` that you already created, `tkinter` will be picked up automatically:

```
source my_venv_1/bin/activate
python
>>>import tkinter as tk
>>>
```

Success!

Answer (score 0):

### Standard troubleshooting steps

Please make sure of the following before concluding that Tkinter needs to be installed somewhere.

- **Does it make sense** in the first place, **to try to use Tkinter** in this program? In particular, **web applications** and similar client-server applications **should generally not try to use any kind of desktop GUI toolkit on the server** - Tkinter included. The server will often not have a physical display, and end users wouldn't be able to see it anyway; most server hosting [will not include Tkinter etc. in their Python support](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/TkinterPygameEtc) on so-called "headless" servers.

  It also doesn't generally make sense to try to "send" a GUI to the client side this way. In a web app, data (HTML/CSS/Javascript) will be sent to the web browser which creates the UI there. For stand-alone programs that will send data to a server, the client should implement the GUI, and use its own logic to interpret data that was sent from the server in order to update the GUI widgets. It makes no sense for the server to try to "control" the application on the client.

  As a **special note for Matplotlib and similar libraries** that optionally display GUI content: it may not be necessary to use specifically Tkinter to see GUI results, and it may be possible to solve the problem without a GUI. In particular, Matplotlib can be told to use a non-GUI "backend" and then save graphs into image files rather than displaying them on screen (which is often more useful anyway). It can also be told to use other GUI backends besides Tkinter. For details, see:

  - ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777)
  - [Generating a PNG with matplotlib when DISPLAY is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882)
  - [How to change backends in matplotlib / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285193)
  - [_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289)
- Is the `import` spelled correctly for this version of Python? [2.x code must refer to `Tkinter` by default, but 3.x must refer to `tkinter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843596).
- **Which installation of Python is in use** for the code? Just like with everything else that can go wrong with running the wrong Python (i.e.: wrong third-party libraries installed for that Python, version incompatible with the code), it's **possible that some installations of Python on a given machine support Tkinter and others do not**.

  Note especially on Linux that just because Tcl/Tk is installed on the system *does not* mean that every Python installation will have access to it. Tkinter support needs to be added to each installation.

  This can interact with the previous issue: suppose a given machine has both a 2.x and a 3.x version installed. Even if Tkinter is available for both, trying to run the code with the wrong version would cause an `ImportError` (assuming there isn't a `SyntaxError` first, from e.g. [trying to use `print` as a statement in 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439)).

  If it's intentional that some Python installations don't support Tkinter on a given system, just make sure that the Tkinter code runs with an installation that supports Tkinter.

  Especially be aware that virtual environments count as separate Python installations. Generally, they will have Tkinter support **if** they were created from a base installation **that had** Tkinter support **when the virtual environment was created**. Generally it is not possible to add Tkinter support *directly* to a virtual environment. Keep in mind that other third-party tools - IDEs like PyCharm, build-toolchain tools like Poetry, and environment management tools like `pyenv` - may create virtual environments - read the documentation and make sure of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

### Special environments

This is a community wiki answer intended to round up answers for dealing with non-standard Python installations. Please edit to add information for them. To start off I am including some links for previous specific questions about these environments, whether or not they were suitably answered.

#### Abaqus

- [Use Tkinter in Abaqus 6.12-1 import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322883)

#### `python3-dbg` (debug build provided by gdb?)

- [GDB: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743762)

#### QGIS

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' in QGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785145)

#### Enthought Canopy

- [Trouble with tkinter install in Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179900)

#### Anaconda

- [Can't import tkinter in python using Mac OSX 10.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554174/) (?)

#### PyPy

#### IronPython / Python.NET

#### Bundled executables created with PyInstaller etc.