# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to compile this simple python program:

```py
from tkinter import Tk,Button
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
def get_date():
    selected_date = cal.get()
    print(f"Selected date: {selected_date}")
root = Tk()
cal = DateEntry(root, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
cal.pack()
btn = Button(root, text="Click Here To Return a Date ", command=get_date)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Expected:
A calendar should appear and when I pick a date the date is printed out.

But I get this error:

> File "/root/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 2, in 
> from tkcalendar import DateEntry
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'

I use Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Any idea of how to get this work?

Comment: Did you `pip install tkcalendar` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Answer (score 0):

### Description:

The `ModuleNotFound` error mostly occurs when a module is not installed or its files are corrupted in which situation its a best practice to redownload the module or upgrade it to a newer version.

### Solution:

Solving this issue will first require some investigation on whether the module is installed or not. In-order to perform this action just type and hit:

```
pip show tkcalendar
```

If the output generated by the above command is this:

```
WARNING: Package(s) not found: tkcalendar
```

This means that the package is not installed, for installing it type and hit:

**For Windows:**

```
pip install tkcalendar
```

**For Linux or MacOS:**

```
pip install tkcalendar
```

If the output generated by the `pip show tkcalendar` is this or somewhat similar to this:

```
Version: 1.6.1
Summary: Calendar and DateEntry widgets for Tkinter
Home-page: https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar
Author: Juliette Monsel
Author-email: j_4321@protonmail.com
License: GPLv3
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Requires: babel
Required-by:
```

This means that the module is installed and just needs an upgrade, for that type and hit:

```
pip install --upgrade tkcalendar
```

This should do the necessary work for you.

### Note:

It is also possible that you are running the code inside of a Python Virtual Environment (`venv`). In that case you have to change you Python Interpreter to the one inside of the `venv` and then install `tkcalendar` or perform the above actions.

Comment: Thank you AshhadDevLab,

the output generated by the above command says that the package is installed.

Upgrading with

pip install --upgrade tkcalendar

says it's already the last version.

I am not using a Python Virtual Environment (venv), I installed the IDE
pyCharm and I am trying to complie the code from within that program.

Please help me if you can

Giovanni

Comment: I can look further in your case if you want, we can discuss this in stackoverflow chat.